# How do i transparent a form in vb6.0?

Tags: vb6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Semi Transparent Form using VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621118/semi-transparent-form-using-vb6)

I want to create a vb application with multiple form that are all transparent with some text on.Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with code only by transparent a form.

VB:
Declare this first

```
Dim g_nTransparency As Integer
Public Const LWA_COLORKEY = 1
Public Const LWA_ALPHA = 2
Public Const LWA_BOTH = 3
Public Const WS_EX_LAYERED = &H80000
Public Const GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
Public Declare Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal Color As Long, ByVal X As Byte, ByVal alpha As Long) As Boolean

Public Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Sub SetTranslucent(ThehWnd As Long, nTrans As Integer)
'SetWindowLong and SetLayeredWindowAttributes are API functions, see MSDN for details
   Dim attrib As Long
   attrib = GetWindowLong(ThehWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE)
   SetWindowLong ThehWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, attrib Or WS_EX_LAYERED
   SetLayeredWindowAttributes ThehWnd, RGB(255, 255, 0), nTrans, LWA_ALPHA    
End Sub

Public Function Transparent_Form()
  g_nTransparency = 190
  If g_nTransparency < 0 Then g_nTransparency = 0
  If g_nTransparency > 255 Then g_nTransparency = 255
  SetTranslucent Translucent.hwnd, g_nTransparency
  Translucent.Show
  mintCount = 0 
End Function
```