# VB Form In Circle Shape

Tags: vb6

I am using VB6. Can anyone tell me how I can make a form in round circle shape?

I have used this code but it shows an error:

```
Private Declare Function CreateRectRgn Lib "gdi32" (ByVal X1 As Long, ByVal Y1 As Long, ByVal X2 As Long, ByVal Y2 As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateEllipticRgn Lib "gdi32" (ByVal X1 As Long, ByVal Y1 As Long, ByVal X2 As Long, ByVal Y2 As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CombineRgn Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hDestRgn As Long, ByVal hSrcRgn1 As Long, ByVal hSrcRgn2 As Long, ByVal nCombineMode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowRgn Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hRgn As Long, ByVal bRedraw As Long) As Long
Private Function fMakeATranspArea(AreaType As String, pCordinate() As Long) As Boolean
```

Comment: This code doesn't actually do anything. It is just a series of declarations. You haven't shown us how you're calling these functions, or what the implementation of the `fMakeATranspArea` function is.

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621118/semi-transparent-form-using-vb6

Answer (score 2):

The `fMakeATranspArea` may look like an API call as well (which it isn't) - but it's missing the body, which is likely your issue that you're confused about.

You can replace your last line with something manual like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    SetWindowRgn Me.hWnd, CreateEllipticRgn(0, 0, 300, 300), 1
End Sub
```

Those numbers you see are the co-ordinates.  I do not suggest you fix `fMakeATranspArea` as it seems to be complex, and over complicating to what you may need.

`CombineRgn` and `CreateRectRgn` are not needed in this case as well.

From the looks of it, you found the source code from here - which has the full implementation:

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCodeAsText.asp?txtCodeId=1617&lngWId=-10